# mobile geolocation mysql windows azure

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile, azure

Hi im following a tutorial and im stuck, can someone please help explain this part, whenever i attempt to write the commands "--host=hostname.cloudapp.net" i get an error saying "sh.exe not a command" im using Git.

Here is a link to the tutorial http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Geolocation-Apps-with-Windows-Azure-Websites-Part-1--The-PHP-Code

Here is the part where i am stuck:

"Setting up MySQL

If you’re running OS X, you should find MySQL in /usr/local/mysql. If you don’t, go ahead and install it. Afterwards, open up a terminal window and navigate to /usr/local/mysql. You’ll then need to connect to your database like so:

$cd /usr/local/mysql 
$mysql --host=hostname.cloudapp.net --user=userName --password=password databasename 
Just replace the hostname, username, password, and databasename with values from your connection string. Once that is done, you can create your database table. Copy and paste this into the terminal and hit enter:

```
CREATE TABLE 'geodata' (
  'Id' char(36) NOT NULL,
  'Type' smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Description' varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Url' varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Location' point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('Id')
)
```

Your response should be something like “Query OK, 0 rows affected”. Your table is now created. Now we can look through the functionality that will power our mobile applications."

I dont understand what he means by "If you don’t, go ahead and install it" but the host database etc. i understand just the mysql part.

Any help is very much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, 
I just needed to download a mysql server.
Locate the bin folder on mysql with the git bash.
then i can use the mysql commands.